# using php to submit form data to MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, forms, insert

I am trying to create a form to submit data into a MySQL database but it is not working. At the moment I have the following error for my INSERT query:

PHP Syntax Check: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in your code

at the moment I have the following php

```
<?php 

 $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "etrading");

 /* check connection */
 if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
     exit();
   }

 //Query
  $query = "INSERT INTO item (Name, Description, img_path, Quantity, Category, Location, Sale_Type, Price,  Duration, Payment) VALUES
 ($_POST['name'], $_POST['description'], $_POST['photo'], $_POST['quantity'], $_POST['category'], $_POST['location'], $_POST['Sale_Type'], $_POST['price'], $_POST['duration'], $_POST['payment'])";

    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if($result){
       echo("<br>Input data is succeed");
} else{
    echo("<br>Input data is fail");
 }

  /* close connection */
  $mysqli->close();

 ?>
```

This is currently what I have for my form. I am yet to still write code in for uploading an image. I am currently trying to get the form to work with no errors before I attempt the image upload.

```
<form id="sellitem" action="sellitem.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return checkForm(this);" >
        <fieldset>
            <h4>Sell Your Item</h4>
            <p><label class="title" for="name">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter item name" name="name" id="name" title="Please enter item name" ><br />

            <label class="title" for="text">Description:</label>
            <textarea name="description" rows="5" cols="33" type="text" placeholder="Please describe your item"  id="description" title="Please describe your item" ></textarea><br />

            <label class="title" for="category">Category:</label>
            <select name="category" id="category" >
                <option value="clothes">Clothes</option>
                <option value="books">Books</option>
                <option value="electronics">Electronics</option>
                <option value="sport">Sport</option>
            </select></p>

            <label class="title" for="location">Location:</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Item Location" name="location" id="location" title="Enter item location" ><br />

            <label class="title" for="name">Sale Type:</label>
            <select name="Sale_Type" id="Sale_Type" >
                <option value="Auction">Auction</option>
                <option value="BuyNow">Buy Now</option>
            </select>

            <label class="title" for="price">Price: $</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="00.00" name="price" id="name" title="Please enter your name" ><br />

            <label class="title" for="name">Quantity:</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Number of items" name="quantity" id="name" title="Number of items" ><br />

            <label class="title" for="name">Duration:</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="End date" name="duration" id="duration" title="End Date" ><br />

            <label class="title" for="name">Payment Type:</label>
            <select name="payment" id="payment" >
                <option value="PayPal">PayPal</option>
                <option value="Bank Deposit">Bank Deposit</option>
                 <option value="Card">Credit Card</option>
            </select><br>
            Select image to upload:
             <input type="file" name="img_path" id="img_path" >


            <div class="submit"><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></div>
            <div class="reset"><input type="reset" value="Reset" /></div>

            </fieldset>

            </form>
```

If I could please get some help as to why this error is appearing. Also a useful link/site to creating a simple upload photo to the MySQL database would also be helpful.

Comment: I think you are using `mysqli` instead of `mysql`.  `$result = mysql_query($query);`. Change it to `$result = mysqli_query($mysqli ,$query);`

Comment: Also a general remark: your code is _wide open_ to sql injection attacks. Please read about the security benefits of using the combination of "prepared statements" and "parameter binding" to prevent this.

Comment: And the `echo` statement is a language construct, not a function. You do not need brackets: `echo "<br>Input data is succeed";`

Comment: About that specific error message: it appears to be not complete. Please add the _full_ error message to the question and tell us which line exactly it refers to. Note: do not post additional details into comments here. There is  an `edit` link below your question. _Use it_.

Comment: Hint to prevent future issues: Do not use the php closing tag at the end of files (`?>`). It is not required there and can actually cause confusing issues.

Comment: also use `extract($_POST);` then `$query = "INSERT INTO item (Name, Description, img_path, Quantity, Category, Location, Sale_Type, Price,  Duration, Payment) VALUES
 ('$name',.....)`

Comment: Error is in your $query. you're not escaping ' and passing it in $query=" " but that doen't end here you're using mysqli_api for connection and performing query through mysql_ so that will be an another error. If eventually you solve your all errors then you'll be trapped in sql injection. so better to start learning some safe code

Comment: @urfusion Nooooooo! 1. this cements the sql injection vulnerability 2.it risks naming collisions with the current scope and 3. it make things only more confusing!

Comment: @arkascha : yes, there are chance for sql injection. but this can be a solution.

Comment: @urfusion _Please_... your advice to use `extract()` really is a bad thing. I suggest you remove it. It does not change a thing here, it should only be used inside functions if at all, preferably only inside small, anonymous functions. Best is not to use it at all.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The code just declares a string variable that contains a MySQL query:
It does not execute the query.
here is the solution

```
<?php 
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "yourdb";

  // Create connection
  $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
 // Check connection
 if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

 $sql = "INSERT INTO table_name (name) VALUES 
      ('".$_POST["name"]."')";

  if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
     echo "New record created successfully";
  } else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
 }

$conn->close();
```

?>

[here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp)

Comment: Would you care to elaborate? Code-only answers are considered bad answers...

Comment: thanks bro. Next time elaborate answers with code

Comment: Hm, sure, but why not add some explaining words to _this_ question?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the mysqli object, therefore the query should be run with

```
$result=$mysqli->query($query);
```

[Php doc](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)